# How to use @abstractmethod to create an abstract interface that specifies the argument structure of its constructor?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I understand why the code below throws and exception, and some ways avoid that exception, but I don't understand the intended way to use @abstractmethod in order to create an abstract interface.

My goal is to

- create an abstract interface Foo that has a single argument constructor
- and an adapter class FooAdapter that can be subclassed by classes intending to implement Foo.

The problem is that if I add in the appropriate calls to "super" in the constructor I will eventually call the abstractmethod and raise an exception.

- Fix #1.  Dont add super.  works but seems wrong since it could drop info needed by other classes, if mixed with other classes
- Fix #2.  Dont add the signature for **init** in the interface.  works, but seems wrong since the whole point of an interface is to DEFINE THE INTERFACE.  and I would not be doing that, at least not for the constructor.

I feel like I am thinking about this wrong.  What the pythonic way??

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Foo(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, my_arg):
        raise NotImplementedError


class FooAdapter(Foo):
    def __init__(self, my_arg):
        super().__init__()
```

FROM THE ACCEPTED ANSWER BELOW

You don't need to use NotImplementedError at all, instead just use 'pass'.
The @abstractmethod mechanism will throw an exception if a subclass does not implement the indicated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `abc.abstarctmethod` [description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> **Note**: Unlike `Java` abstract methods, these abstract methods **may have** an implementation. This implementation can be called via the `super()` mechanism from the class that overrides it. This could be useful as an end-point for a super-call in a framework that uses cooperative multiple-inheritance.

Therefore you need just put stub doing nothing instead of raising `NotImlementedError`.

Comment: Oh!  Got it, so the answer in my case is to NOT use "NotImplementedError" at all.  and use the @abstractmethod mechanism to ensure that all subclasses do add some kind of method here.  Got it.  Thanks!  my confusion came from thinking that I should use NotImplementedError to catch non-implementation, but that is wrong in this case.